# How to find number of pairs which have maximum difference in their values among all other pairs?

Tags: c, arrays

I calculated difference between each pair and then stored the maximum difference pertaining to that element in the same array at that location only , for instance array is 1 2 3 , so a[0]=2 , a[1]=1 , since difference of 1 is maximum with 3 and difference of 2 is maximum with 3 , Now whatever manipulations I do I perform with the array size reduced by 1 , so Now I calculate the maximum difference value and place it in 0th index and after that I run a loop till the size of reduced array and count the no of times this maximum value appears , but this approach takes too long , can someone suggest some simple logic .Input is of the form 
No of test cases is for e.g 2
no of elements in first array
maximum no of pairs in 1st array
no of elements in 2nd array
maximum no of elements in 2nd array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int max=0;
int main()
{
    int test_no, n1,n2,i,j,a,b,count1=1,count2=1;
    scanf("%d",&test_no);
    printf("\n");
    scanf("%d",&n1);
    printf("\n");
    int arr1[n1];
    for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d ",&arr1[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n1-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<=n1-1;j++)
        {
          a=abs(arr1[i]-arr1[j]);
          if(max<=a)
          max=a;
        }
        arr1[i]=max;
        max=0;
    }
    int temp;
    max=arr1[0];
    for(i=1;i<n1-1;i++)
    {
        if(max<arr1[i])
        {
            temp=max;
            max=arr1[i];
            arr1[i]=temp;
            arr1[0]=max;
        }
    }
    for(i=1;i<n1-1;i++)
    {
        if(arr1[i]==arr1[0])
        {
            count1++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    scanf("%d",&n2);
    int arr2[n2];
    max=0;
    for(i=0;i<n2;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d ",&arr2[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n2-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<=n2-1;j++)
        {
            a=abs(arr2[i]-arr2[j]);
            if(max<=a)
            max=a;
        }
        arr2[i]=max;
        max=0;
    }
    temp=0;
    max=arr2[0];
    for(i=1;i<n2-1;i++)
    {
        if(max<arr2[i])
        {
            temp=max;
            max=arr2[i];
            arr2[i]=temp;
            arr2[0]=max;
        }
    }
    for(i=1;i<n2-1;i++)
    {
        if(arr2[i]==arr2[0])
        {
            count2++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d \n",count1);
    printf("%d",count2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I suggest you should format your code properly.

Comment: Are you trying to find out the maximum difference between 2 adjacent array elements?
You have the simple option of using a temporary variable which holds the max value and then comparing each difference with that value and resetting the max value, if a new pair with higher difference is found. 
---Pseudo code - 

    |int maxValue = <minvalue> for the type.|

      |loop through the array, take adjacent numbers|
           |calculate difference|
           |If difference > maxValue|
                 |maxValue = difference|
.....

Comment: actually issue is that once I get the maximum difference I even have to count it how many times I get it , that's where I am stuck .

Comment: Why do you "reduce" the array  (aka skip last element)? It seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort the array (this takes n log n time).

The maximum difference is now obviously the value of the last element minus that of the first.

To get that same difference, you need **the same first element and the same end element**<sup>*</sup>, so that you only need to count how many elements are equal to the first (say 4), how many elements are equal to the last (say 3), and take the lesser of the two values (here 3).

```
size_t i;
for (i = 1; i < arrayLength/2; i++) {
    if ((sortedArray[i] != sortedArray[0])
        ||
        (sortedArray[n-1-i] != sortedArray[n-1])) {
        break;
    }
}
// i is now the number you need.
```

To sort an array in C you also have a ready-made library function.

Or you can do this in O(N) time, by simply scanning the array:

```
int minVal = INT_MIN;
int maxVal = INT_MAX;
int cntMin = 0;
int cntMax = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (arr[i] < minVal) {
        minVal = arr[i];
    }
    if (arr[i] > maxVal) {
        maxVal = arr[i];
    }
    if (arr[i] == minVal) { cntMin++; }
    if (arr[i] == maxVal) { cntMax++; }
}
if (minVal == maxVal) {
    return n/2;
}
return min(cntMin, cntMax);
```

Example:

```
0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 6 6
```

Maximum difference is 6 and is to be found 3 times.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 6 6
```

Maximum difference is still 6, and is to be found once only.

If you want to count **all** possible pairs (e.g. in [ 0<sub>1</sub>, 0<sub>2</sub>, 6<sub>1</sub>, 6<sub>2</sub>, 6<sub>3</sub> ] you want to have (0<sub>1</sub>,6<sub>1</sub>) ... (0<sub>2</sub>, 6<sub>3</sub>) ), even if your note about *removing elements* seems to indicate otherwise, then instead of returning the minimum of cntMin and cntMax, just return their product. If they are equal, return N*(N-1) ).

--

<sup>(*) to get the same difference with two different numbers, one of them has to be either less than the minimum, or more than the maximum, of the initial range, which is contradictory. E.g. to get 6 other than from 6 and 0, you would need 7 and 1, or 5 and -1. But 7 is more than 6, and -1 is less than 0. So your array's maximum difference once it includes either 7 or -1 is no longer 6.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is count how many times the smallest and the largest number are present in the array. When you have done that the number of pairs is found by a simple multiplications.

This can be done like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define N 7

int main(void) {
    int arr[N] = {1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 5, 5};
    int max = INT_MIN;
    int min = INT_MAX;
    int i;
    int countmax = 0;
    int countmin = 0;

    for (i=0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        if (arr[i] > max)
        {
            // Found new max value --> reset counter to 1
            countmax = 1;
            max = arr[i];
        }
        else if (arr[i] == max)
        {
            // Found same max value --> increment counter
            countmax++;
        }
        if (arr[i] < min)
        {
            countmin = 1;
            min = arr[i];
        }
        else if (arr[i] == min)
        {
            countmin++;
        }
    }

    if (max == min)
    {
        // Special case: All elements are the same
        printf("%d pairs with difference 0 found\n", N*(N-1)/2);
    else
    {
        printf("%d pairs with difference %d found\n", countmin * countmax, abs(max-min));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
6 pairs with difference 4 found
```